# Mulesoft ESB - Send query-param even when value is null

Tags: mule

I have a server that requires all parameters sent in the url even if the value is null, however it seems that the HTTP Endpoint only sends a query-param when the value is not null.

Example:
I need the request to be:
http://example.com/?v1=&v2=&v3=something&v4=

But, it seems to create the request as:
http://example.com/?v3=something

Example code:

```
<http:request-builder>
<http:query-param paramName="v1" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.v1]"/>
<http:query-param paramName="v2" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.v2]"/>
<http:query-param paramName="v3" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.v3]"/>
<http:query-param paramName="v4" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.v4]"/>
</http:request-builder>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting it to an empty string using a ternary operator instead. Example:

```
<http:query-param paramName="v1" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.v1 != null ? message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.v1 : '']"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... how can I log the url it is building?

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? I believe this was fixed in this [issue](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8966). However, the expected URL in that case would be http://example.com/?v1&v2&v3=something&v4.

Comment: Using 3.7.3... That may be what is happening... I tested the server and apparently it also expects the equal sign for each variable. I think they are manually parsing the url... so at this point I may have to give up and build the query parameters manually. I originally assumed the server I am connecting to was RFC3986 compliant.